# 画像要素を他の要素より先に表示させる方法

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

現在WEBページを運営しておりますが、初回読み込み時に背景→テキスト→画像の順番で表示されます。
テキストはWeb Fontで、画像はjQueryを使用していますので、個人的には納得（CDNとキャッシュを利用して２回目以降の読み込みはいたって快適）していたのですが「せめてヘッダー画像だけでも先に表示できないか」との要望を受けてしまい現在困っております。
画像の軽量化/最適化やコードの圧縮なども行っております。
他に何か有効的な方法がございましたらご教授お願いいたします。

使用CMS：WordPress
ヘッダー：スライダー(Rev Slider)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

読み込み時の表示順をコントロールする場合。  
後から表示させたいものは初期表示を全て非表示にしておいて  
ロード完了(onload等)のイベントをトリガーにして  
順次表示させていくと好きな順番に出来ます。

慣れたら色々と 応用が効きますよ。

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>サンプル1</title>
<style>
.main_off {
 display: none;
}
.main_on {
 display: block;
}
</style>
<script>
function main_on(){
 document.getElementById('main').className = "main_on"; 
}
</script>
<noscript>
 <style>
  .main_off { display: block; }
 </style>
</noscript>
</head>
<body>

<header>
<!-- 画像のonloadイベントで本文のcssを変更 -->
<img src="abcd.jpg" onload="main_on();" />
</header>

<section id="main" class="main_off" >
本文
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
この方法なら管理の必要がなく実装できてなおかつ簡単ですね。
一度この方法で試してみます。

Answer (score 3):

Data URI スキームを用いるのはどうでしょう。Data URI スキーム では `img` 要素の `src` 属性の中に、直接画像データを書き込みます。よって HTML がブラウザに読み込まれる時に同時に読み込まれるため、かなり初期に表示されると期待できます。ただし画像データを埋め込む分、HTMLのサイズは大きくなります。加えて、何を最初に表示するかはブラウザの実装に依存しますので、絶対とは言えません。

実際の例は [インラインで画像をHTMLに埋め込むData URLスキーム](https://www.softel.co.jp/blogs/tech/archives/2117) を見れば、Data URI スキーム がどういったものかは即座に理解できるでしょう。

仕様については Wikipedia の [Data URI scheme](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) が参考になります。また [画像をdataURL(MIME Type + base64文字列)に変換する](http://hi0a.com/demo/img-base64-datauri/) のように、画像をData URIへ手軽に変換するWebアプリもあります。

Comment: imgにもスキームが使えるのですね、初めて知りました。
ですが今回はwordpressを使用しておりまして、個人で運営する分は上記の方法で問題ないのですが、プラグインを使用しているため相対パスが限界です（管理は私が行っていない為）。
ですが上記の方法はすごく個人的に気になりますので、一度試してみようと思います。
ご返答ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

image.onload イベントを使えないでしょうか。
ページをヘッダー部分とそれ以外に分け、ヘッダー画像の読み込みが終わったら、残りの部分を表示します。

```
<body>

  <img id='img'> 
  <script>
    var img = document.getElementById('img');
    img.onload = function () {
      //alert('ヘッダー画像読み込みました');
      // ヘッダー画像を読み込んだら残りを表示
      document.getElementById('main').src = 'main.html';
    }
    img.src = 'header.png';
  </script>

  <iframe id='main' />

</body>
```

Comment: 上記の方法ですと結構読み込み速度は落ちてしまいますか？
そこは検証してみるのが一番ですね。
上記の方法でテストしてご報告させていただきます。
ありがとうございました。